# Save an Image with TextureView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I hope you can fix my problem:
I have got a textureview to takes photos but when he capture photos, the file who need to contain the picture is empty. I don't know where and what is the problem. I just think that the problem is when the file is created. Thank you to help me.

This is a part of my code :

```
private void takePicture() throws CameraAccessException, IOException {
    if(cameraDevice == null){
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
    Size[] jpegSizes = null;

    jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    if(jpegSizes!=null && jpegSizes.length>0){
        width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
        height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
    }

    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
    List<Surface> outputSurface = new ArrayList<>(2);
    outputSurface.add(reader.getSurface());

    outputSurface.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
    captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);

    int rotation = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));

    // First I get the path to gallery and crate new Album to my app

    File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    mImageFolder = new File(file, "Fluico");
    if (!mImageFolder.exists()) {
        if (!mImageFolder.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Fluicophoto", "failed to create directory");
        }
    }

    /*Second I cut mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
    from onActivityCreated and add here with the new path from my Album*/

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "IMAGE_" + timestamp + "_";
    file = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", mImageFolder);
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file need to be save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;

            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            try {
                save(bytes);
            } finally {
                image.close();
            }
        }
    };

    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener,mBackgroundHandler);

    final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{
                createCameraPreview();
            }catch (CameraAccessException e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "capture not comleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured( CameraCaptureSession session) {
            try {
                session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "capture not configured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed( CameraCaptureSession session) {

        }
    },mBackgroundHandler);
}

private void save(byte[] bytes) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "it's good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nagrom83, Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
 File myDir;
 String fname;
 String id = "123456";
 int count = 0;

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                myDir = new File(root + "/PhotoApp/" + id);
                myDir.mkdirs();
                count++;

                counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));

                fname = "" + id + "-" + count + ".jpg";

                File file = new File(myDir, fname);
                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
```

This code will create a folder PhotoApp and inside the folder, all the images will store.

You can get full code with the camera in my GitHub:

**Link:** https://github.com/abhishekhzb/quick_camera

Comment: I do what did you say but I now, he juste save nothing

Comment: I think no. I don't know how he can do that.

Comment: I will that the textureview was save like an image (.jpeg) when i click on the button "take photo"

Comment: Thank you if you can to help me

Comment: Sure I will help you

Comment: Thank, so what did I need to do? (It is perfect if you have a part of code for example)

Comment: Wait if possible I will share the full code by tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @Nagrom83,
I have edited the answer, please have a look.

Comment: Hi, thank for your app but she don't save the picture and the folder in the phone storage?

Comment: Ok sorry, I saw that he save. So thank you sooo much to help me

Comment: In my code directly you can use without saving, or if saved there is a function in my code for delete image also. Just you need to understand the code and you can use it.